# Как посчитать количество символов, входящих в каждую из последовательностей в FASTA файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython

Решала задачу с сайта rosalind.info. Дано: FASTA-файл. Нужно: получить процент, который составляют `G` и `C` от всех символов в каждой из последовательностей.

Пришла к следующему решению:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
filename = "rosalind_gc.txt"
count = 0

for record in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    seqs = record
    a = seqs[count].count('A')
    t = seqs[count].count('T')
    g = seqs[count].count('G')
    c = seqs[count].count('C')

    Q = (g+c)/(a+g+t+c)

    print("Record " + record.id + ", GC content " + str(Q))
    count = count + 1
```

Проблема в том, что оно выдаёт вместо необходимого процентного содержания `G` и `C` нули.

В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [43]: for rec in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    ...:     pct = (rec.seq.count("G") + rec.seq.count("C")) / len(rec.seq)
    ...:     print(f'Record [{rec.id}], G+C percentage: {pct:.2%}')
    ...:
Record [Rosalind_6694], G+C percentage: 51.44%
Record [Rosalind_4678], G+C percentage: 49.07%
Record [Rosalind_5949], G+C percentage: 48.77%
Record [Rosalind_8608], G+C percentage: 52.15%
Record [Rosalind_6370], G+C percentage: 50.63%
Record [Rosalind_2598], G+C percentage: 50.89%
Record [Rosalind_4988], G+C percentage: 47.94%
```

если надо посчитать процентное соотношение вхождений подпоследовательности `GC` (где `C` следует за `G`):

```
In [44]: for rec in SeqIO.parse(filename, "fasta"):
    ...:     pct = rec.seq.count("GC") / len(rec.seq)
    ...:     print(f'Record [{rec.id}], GC percentage: {pct:.2%}')
    ...:
Record [Rosalind_6694], GC percentage: 6.22%
Record [Rosalind_4678], GC percentage: 6.44%
Record [Rosalind_5949], GC percentage: 7.46%
Record [Rosalind_8608], GC percentage: 7.29%
Record [Rosalind_6370], GC percentage: 5.84%
Record [Rosalind_2598], GC percentage: 6.31%
Record [Rosalind_4988], GC percentage: 5.91%
```