# Подсчёт символов в списке на конкретных позициях

Tags: python, строки, счетчики

Из файла получен список с элементами, каждый элемент представляет собой строку из букв и символов (в моём случае чередование `"a"`, `"c"`, `"g"`, `"t"`, `"-"`). В каждой строке 200 символов.

Таких строк очень много, и необходимо по каждой позиции (по столбикам) во всех строках посчитать количество каждого типа элементов.

Пример:

```
['agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----', 
 'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaata', 
 'gcgatcgtggcgcgggcggg']
```

Должен получиться результат:

```
1: a=2, g=1, c=0, t=0, -=0
2: a=1, g=1, c=1, t=0, -=0
3: a=0, g=0, c=3, t=0, -=0
...
200. a=2, g=1, c=0, t=0, -=4
```

Но понятное дело, что цифры будут намного больше, потому что там несколько сотен тысяч строк. Но столбиков всего 200, т.к. по 200 символов в строке.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [модулем `biopython`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846246/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-fa)

Comment: А почему `3: a=0, g=0, c=3, t=0, -=0` а не `3: a=1, g=1, c=0, t=1, -=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections, itertools, string

item_list = ['agtcgtcgatcgatcgatcga----', 'aaagggtctgcgatgcgaata', 'gcgatcgtggcgcgggcggg', ]
all_keys = set(itertools.chain(*item_list))

line = ''
for (num, item) in enumerate(zip(*item_list), start=1):
    print(line)

    count = collections.Counter(item)
    for k in all_keys:
        count.setdefault(k, 0)
        continue

    sort_count = sorted(count, key=lambda v: [(v not in string.ascii_letters), v, ])
    line = '{num}: {k}'.format(num=num, k=', '.join('{k}={v}'.format(k=k, v=count[k]) for k in sort_count))
    continue
print(line.replace('{}:'.format(num), '{}.'.format(num), 1))
```

out:

```
1: a=2, c=0, g=1, t=0, -=0
2: a=1, c=1, g=1, t=0, -=0
3: a=1, c=0, g=1, t=1, -=0
...
20. a=0, c=0, g=2, t=1, -=0
```

Comment: А как вывести более красиво эти значения? чтобы отображалось примерно как я написал в условии (чтобы было видно номер строки)? Вроде со значениями в 'r' можно работать, но я не могу понять как их сделать красивыми

Comment: чтобы отображалось как написано - примерно так